# Set custom table style as default when inserting tables in content editor web part

Tags: css, branding

I've created a table style ex:

```
.testTable-default
{
 -ms-name:"Tabell - test";
 border:1px solid $borderColor; // sass syntax
 margin: 8px 0;
 width:98%;
}
```

I've removed all other table styles and the custom table style shows in the ribbon. But how can I always apply the style to all tables in content editor web part?

What I want is when inserting tables it always uses that specific table branding without having to click in the ribbon on that specific table styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't apply any particular style to a table inserted in a CEWP, it'll get applied the class `ms-rteTable-default`.

So, instead of what you have done, you can override -in your custom css file- that class:

```
.ms-rteTable-default{
   -ms-name:"Tabell - test";
   border:1px solid $borderColor; // sass syntax
   margin: 8px 0;
   width:98%;
}
```

Just make sure to load your css after the core.css stylesheet